# How to check if requested data exist

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with data support. I pass in template different names of variables. When I send one variable I've got error: Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError.

I send to view variables named `btn`, `delete` and `undo`.

I've done it in this way

```
try:
       task = List.objects.get(id=data['undo'])
   except:
       try:
           task = List.objects.get(id=data['delete'])
       except.....
```

And that is working properly but I've got a challenge to do it in a better way.

There is my view

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        type_of = request.POST.get('type')
        if data['description']:
            new_task = List()
            new_task.create_task(data['title'], data['description'], type_of)
        else:
            return render(request, './index.html', {'context': "error: field cannot be empty"})
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = request.GET
        try:
            task = List.objects.get(id=data['btn'])
            for x in task_status:
                if task.type_of == task_status[x]:
                    task.type_of = task_status[x + 1]
                    break
            task.save()
        except:
            try:
                task = List.objects.get(id=data['delete'])
                task.delete()
            except:
                try:
                    task = List.objects.get(id=data['undo'])
                    for x in task_status:
                        if task.type_of == task_status[x]:
                            task.type_of = task_status[x - 1]
                            break
                    task.save()
                except:
                    task_list_back_log, task_list_to_do, task_list_in_progress, task_list_done = return_filter_lists()
                    return render(request, './index.html',
                                  {'back_log': task_list_back_log, 'to_do': task_list_to_do,
                                   'in_progress': task_list_in_progress,
                                   'done': task_list_done})
```

But when I deleted my try-except block and pass to view for example only `data['undo']` I've got error

> Exception Value: 'btn'

The problem is that when i load template first time my data query is empty...
Is there any way to check which variable exists in view and use it?

Comment: Can you post the entire code for your `views.py`? This way is easy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List.objects.filter(id=data['undo']).exists()
```

will return True or False depending on whether the query finds something or not.

If the question referes to checking whether data['undo'] exists, then:

```
if 'undo' in data:
  do_some_magic()
```

will do.

Comment: But when i load my template first time, any of this data variables does not even exist and i've got error - Exception Value: 'btn' because data query is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
 task = List.objects.filter(id=data['undo']).first()
```

return first record